# Order totals showing wrong way around

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, totals

How can I change the position of the order totals (incl. tax / excl. tax) in the tax calculation? As it should show the total including tax below the total excluding tax but at the moment it does not.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Other than the single totals (subtotal, tax, shipping, discount) which you can reorder in *Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales > Checkout Totals Sort Order*, the grand totals are hard coded in the template

`Magento/Tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total.html`

```
<tr class="grand totals incl">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: inclTaxLabel"></strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': inclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grand totals excl">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: exclTaxLabel"></strong>
    </th>Magento/Tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': exclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getGrandTotalExclTax()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Override this template in your theme and change the order of these two `<tr>` table rows.

This template is for the cart. For the checkout summary, do the same in `Magento/Tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html`

Comment: Hi thanks for that quick reply, where do i find this coding page?

Comment: for magento 2 right?

Comment: The files are either in `app/code/Magento/Tax/view/...` or `vendor/magento/module-tax/view/...`, depending on your type of installation. But you should never change core files directly. Instead, copy them to your theme and modify them there. You can learn about template overriding and custom themes here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html#override